# What is the fastest way to process large .asc files?

Tags: python, pandas, canoe

I currently have .asc log files that have been generated from CANoe. I am using python to analyze these files. These files are pretty big(anywhere from .5GB-2GB). To read/analyze the data I am converting the data to a dataframe and I am using the following lines of code to do this:

```
    log=can.ASCReader(filePath)
    log=[*log]
    df_data = [{'timestamp':m.timestamp, 'data':m.data} for m in log]
    df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
```

Through my analysis, the part that is taking the longest is converting the iterator to a list. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing that. I am also open to doing the entire process a whole new way if it is faster. Currently a .6gb .asc file is taking about 19 minutes to run. Any help/suggestiosn would be appreciated!

Comment: What does the function DataFrame() do? If it can be re-written to take an iterator, that would eliminate the conversion.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker pd.DataFrame converts the list of dictionaries to a dataframe. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: About which line are you talking? Is it line 2 in your example code, that is taking so long? Why is this line there at all?

Comment: @M.Spiller Yes line two is what is taking so long. I am doing that line so that I can convert the iterator to a list so that I can create a list of dictionaries to transform into a dataframe table.

Comment: But in line 3 you are simply iterating over the list. Why don't you just iterate over the iterator returned from line 1?

Comment: @M.Spiller how would you do that? How would you go from an iterator to a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @AJHello just drop line 2

Comment: @M.Spiller ah I understand. Yeah that sped up the script slightly(by about 1 minute). Perhaps that's as fast as it's going to get however.

Comment: @AJHello How do you want your dataframe to look like? Use the timestamp as an index and the 8 data bytes as columns?

Comment: I'm okay with the timestamp and data as two separate columns. m.data returns a bytearray and having a bytearray column is fine with me.

Comment: Have added a suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most time-consuming part is most likely reading from disk. This cannot be avoided.

However you can make sure that you do not put unnecessary data into memory or copy it around.

Try the following:

```
import operator
log=can.ASCReader(filePath)
pd.DataFrame(data=map(operator.attrgetter('timestamp', 'data'), log))
```

`ASCReader` will return an iterator, i.e. not reading data until you use `log`.

As you are only interested in the values behind `timestamp` and `data`, we declare and *attrgetter* for these two attributes. That is a function that takes an object and will return just the two given attributes of that object.

For applying this attrgetter to the log we will use `map`. `map` will apply the attrgetter to each element of `log`. `map` also returns an iterator, i.e. it will not read and store any data until used.

Finally we give the map into pandas as the source of data for constructing a `DataFrame`.

Doing it like this should be the approach with the least amount of copying data around or handling unnecessary data. YMMV

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think this is the fastest we can get it to.